# Set path of log file at root of spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, log4j

In my case,
i have configured log4j.xml like

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" />
<param name="File" value="${app.root}" />
<param name="Append" value="true" />
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="20000KB" />
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="400" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n%n" />
</layout>
```

i have to generate log file at path at

**String loggerpath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");**

I am using

```
System.setProperty("app.root", loggerpath+"\\oeslogger.log");
```

but it doesn't works.
Please suggest me solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The point of configurable logging is that the config file is more easily changed than the program, so i fail to see what you are trying to accomplish. Can't you just set the file to "oeslogger.log" in the log4j.xml?

In any case, it seems your logger is already configured by the time you set the system property app.root. That's why the change is not working. In order to change a logging property on the fly you'd have to use Log4j's API instead. So you could try something like:

```
Logger ll = Logger.getLogger("<NAME OF LOGGER>");
FileAppender fa = (FileAppender) ll.getAppender("FILE");
fa.setFile(loggerpath + "\\oeslogger.log");
fa.activateOptions();
```

very early in the code.